# Java Internationalization

Tags: java, internationalization

I have a Java string that I'm having trouble manipulating.  I have a String, s,  that has a value of 丞 (a Chinese character I chose at random, I don't speak Chinese).  If I call

```
String t = new String(s.getBytes());
if (s.equals(t))
    System.out.println("String unchanged");
else
    System.out.println("String changed");
```

Then I get the String changed result.  Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I figured this out, sorry for the post.  I was using the default Java Charset, instead of explicitly casting it as a UTF-8 Charset.  It works now.

Answer (score 6):

Because [that method](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29):

> *Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the **platform's default** charset*

If your default charset is ie `US-ASCII` you won't get the same bytes used by that Chinese letter

I imagine an extra bit/byte may be added/droppped in the process.

Try  using [getBytes( String charSetName )](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29)

```
public byte[] getBytes(String charsetName)
```

Using the correct [charsetName](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)

Answer (score 2):

The getBytes() method uses the default encoding. According to the docs:

> The CharsetEncoder class should be used when more control over the encoding process is required.

Answer (score 1):

String t = new String(s.getBytes()); may create string using ASCII as default charset. Use following method to create the string with charsetName as UTF-8

String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length, String charsetName)